# How to configure ActiveRecord database connection with mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mysql2

Hey everyone Having an issue using ActiveRecord with the 'mysql2' gem. I'm using rails 4.0.4 There are these lines in my config/application.rb

```
# Pick the frameworks you want: 
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

when i try to run 'rails g model user' i get

```
 invoke  active_record
 /Users/edjasper/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties4.0.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `database_configuration': Could not load database configuration. No such file - /Users/edjasper/Desktop/associations_challenge_8/config/database.yml (RuntimeError
```

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you don't have database.yml in config dir
smth like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: my_db_name
  username: root
  password: my_password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
  secure_auth: false
```

also you should already have database.yml.example in your config dir for sample

by the way error message already told you about it :)

```
No such file - /Users/edjasper/Desktop/associations_challenge_8/config/database.yml
```